# Strcpy function changing a unrelated shared memory data

Tags: c, shared-memory, strcpy

I'm a student working on a simple C program that implements two shared memory segments. The thing is that when I use strcpy function with the pointer to the second memory segment called nptr2 changes the value of the firt memory segment with the name nptr.

I've been reading another questions that were solved putting nulls at the end of the string because the string that was being copied had not a null terminating caracter. But I expect that's not my case, as I'm using fgets. I'm showing you the output of some printf I've added to my code to see easier what's happening.

### Struct used for nptr

```
struct estadistikak{
int erabiltzaile;
int bbluzera;
int mezukop;
int karakkop;
};
```

### Memory segment declarations and attachments

```
int memid,memid2;
char mezua[50],*nptr2;
struct shmid_ds buff;
struct estadistikak *nptr;

if ((memid=shmget(0x1234L,sizeof(mezua),0600|IPC_CREAT))<0){
    perror("shmget error");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("%d\n",memid);

if((nptr2=(char*)shmat(memid,0,0))==(char*)-1){
    perror("shmat error");
    exit(-1);
}

//Estatistiken memoria sortu eta atzitu
if ((memid2=shmget(0x12345L,sizeof(stats),0600|IPC_CREAT))<0){
    perror("shmget error");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("%d\n",memid);

if((nptr=(struct estadistikak*)shmat(memid,0,0))==(struct estadistikak*)-1){
    perror("shmat error");
    exit(-1);
}
```

### The part in which the problem happends

Notice that nptr and nptr2 are two different memory pointers that had no relation between them.

```
printf("Sartu nahi duzun mezua:\n");
fflush(stdout);
__fpurge(stdin);
fgets(mezua,50,stdin);

printf("Before: %d\n",nptr->erabiltzaile);
strcpy(nptr2,mezua);
printf("After: %d\n",nptr->erabiltzaile);
strcpy(mezua2,nptr2);
printf("Mi mensaje: %s\n",mezua2);
```

### The output with printfs

```
Sartu nahi duzun mezua:
asdf
Before: 1
After: 1717859169
Mi mensaje: asdf
```

Thanks for your time and have a nice code!

Comment: You need to allocate space for nptr2 before you strcpy mezua to it.  Can't see the declaration of mezua2 anywhere.  If it is a pointer, then it needs space allocation too.

Comment: @MuGiK Why do you assume `nptr` and `nptr2` point to different locations ? Both `shmat` calls use `memid`, you're not using `memid2`.

Comment: @cup Sorry, my mistake, when editing the question I've ereased that declaration. It's equal to mezua:  char mezua2[50]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach to the same `memid` twice:

```
if ((memid=shmget(0x1234L,sizeof(mezua),0600|IPC_CREAT))<0){
    perror("shmget error");
    exit(-1);
}

if((nptr2=(char*)shmat(memid,0,0))==(char*)-1){
    perror("shmat error");
    exit(-1);
}

//Estatistiken memoria sortu eta atzitu
if ((memid2=shmget(0x12345L,sizeof(stats),0600|IPC_CREAT))<0){
    perror("shmget error");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("%d\n",memid);

if((nptr=(struct estadistikak*)shmat(memid,0,0))==(struct estadistikak*)-1){
    perror("shmat error");
    exit(-1);
}
```

The second should be:

```
if((nptr=(struct estadistikak*)shmat(memid2,0,0))==(struct estadistikak*)-1){
    perror("shmat error");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Having said that, it seems cock-eyed to have `nptr2` attached to `memid` and `nptr` attached to `memid2`.  I'd go with consistent suffixes:

```
nptr1    memid1
nptr2    memid2
```

Hence:

```
if ((memid1 = shmget(0x1234L, sizeof(mezua), 0600|IPC_CREAT)) < 0)
    err_exit("shmget 1");

if ((nptr1 = (char*)shmat(memid1, 0, 0)) == (char*)-1)
    err_exit("shmat 1");

if ((memid2 = shmget(0x12345L, sizeof(stats), 0600|IPC_CREAT)) < 0)
    err_exit("shmget 2");

if ((nptr2 = (struct estadistikak*)shmat(memid2, 0, 0)) == (struct estadistikak*)-1)
    err_exit("shmat 2");
```

And `err_exit()` might be as simple as:

```
void err_exit(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Though I usually use a more complex variable-arguments, `printf`-like function.

Answer (score 0):

There would seem to be three explanations for this:

1. Your implementation of `strcpy` is broken.
2. The pointers `nptr` and `nptr2` do not refer to distinct locations in memory.
3. The pointer `nptr2` refers to a block of length less than 50, and you are therefore overwriting that block.

I personally think that the first option is unlikely. So, concentrate on the others. Check the addresses of `nptr` and `nptr2`. Check that they are not overlapping and that `nptr2` refers to a block of length at least 50.

Comment: Typing the command ipcs in console there are created two memory segments. First key:0x00001234 shmid:458754 perms:600 bytes:50 nattch:4. Second key:0x00012345 shmid:491527 perms:600 bytes:16 nattch:0. So, the lengths are OK. I don't know how to see if the segments are overlapping. Any idea? Thanks for being so clear ;D

Comment: Solved. Chnossos was correct, in the second shmat I used memid intead of memid2. Problems happend when using copy&paste